# App with embedded dll wont run on another computer

Tags: c#, dll

Ok so built this app and it's an assignment so I wanted to embed some dll in it so I would only have one file when submitting it. The dll is only used for some UI controls and visuals, nothing else

I went through the necessary steps of setting `Copy Local` to `false` under references and setting `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource` but the problem I have is that if I copy the application exe to another pc it won't run unless I copy the referenced dll into the same directory of the exe so it seems to me that it's not loading the embedded dll file or I may have set up something wrong

Just to note though, the app does run fine on my pc, the one I created on, without needing the referenced dll next to the exe file.

Here is the code I used:

```
//other using statements
using System.Reflection;
using library; //<--- reference to embedded dll

namespace app {
public partial class Form1 : Form1 {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetAsyncKeyState(int i);

    private string embeddedFile = "app.library.dll";

    public Form1() {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) {
        using(var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(embeddedFile)) { //<-- debugging shows a System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream exception here
            byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
            return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
        }
    }

    ///
    /// some unrelated code
    ///
}
```

Comment: Bug is in the code you did not show - somewhere you use that other assembly before setting AssemblyResolve handler.

Comment: You will need to assign the assemblyresolve way earlier. Best would be in the static void main.

Comment: @CSharpie "Best" is not necessary good enough so :) depending on what OP wrote `main` still may be too late.

Comment: You need to test this the way it will run on the other machine.  Use Tools > Options > Debugging > General, untick "Suppress JIT optimization...."  Then Build > Configuration Manager > Active solution configuration = Release.  Press F5.  Assemblies are loaded by the JIT compiler.  Optimization plays an important role, it will try to get methods inlined and that gets assemblies loaded earlier than you'd expect.